# I want my 40px div to be cloned until its parent's height. So I have to partition the height of parent into 40 equal parts. How can I achieve this?

Tags: jquery

[image]Currently I am cloning child into 10 times but I want it to be cloned until parent div height.

```js
var x = $(".kupon_parent").height();
alert(x);//alerts height of parent div
var e = $('.kupon_parent_border');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  e.clone().insertAfter(e); //clones 10 times
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kupon_parent">  
 <div class="border" id="boder">
  <div class="kupon_parent_border"></div>  
 </div>
 <div class="kupon_info">
  <h3>Lorem ipsum </h3>
 </div>
 <form class="kupon_form">
  <input class="user_input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
  <textarea class="user_input" type="text" placeholder="message"></textarea>
  <div class="submit_form">
   <button type="submit" class="submit_btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

This is what I am trying to achieve. And currently I am getting the height of parent and dividing it by 55 as my semicircle is of height 55, the number I get from this division is the number of times cloning is happening. But I am not sure is it the correct way of doing it? The result is Correct according to my expectations but the method I am using is correct or not?

Comment: Please include your html.

Comment: The element with the class `kupon_parent_border` does not have a height. so you're going to get into an infinite loop if you actually did what you're supposed to do, which is check its height and clone it until you have enough to fill the parent.

Comment: Yes exactly, @HereticMonkey I have added the screenshot of what my expectations are and I am getting the result but is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: I don't understand how your code matches up with the screenshot.... I see no need for the `border` element or the jQuery code at all given the HTML. The appearance of the element could be created solely through CSS, but that's the one thing you haven't shared.

Comment: Actually I was creating the border design of that kupon with css but I want that semicircles of border to increase when i increase the height of the kupon.. so I creates before and after pseudo-element on that border and then cloning it as height increase.. so the whole border should look the same in any height..